# jquery mobile navbar

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

navbar in jquery mobile is quick to create a horizontal menu for mobile, here: http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

The issue I got here once I change from vertical screen to horizontal screen, I see the navbar has a gap at right. It should has the width is 100%.

See the picture below:
[image]

Can anyone who know about this issue please help to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using the exact sample code provided in the docs? Please post your HTML. -- Are you testing on a mobile device, a desktop pc browser or an emulator?

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you have 4 tabs in your navigation bar, they will all have a width of 25%.
But, for example, if your div or device is 102 pixels large, each tab will be 25 pixels width, and there will be a gap of 2 pixels.
I see your screen is 609 pixels width, maybe it comes from here. 
Try to adjust margin/padding/border so that the whole things is divisible by 4.